# margin-top não surte efeito em texto dentro da div

Tags: html, css, front-end, div

Estou tentando aplicar `margin-top` na *tag* **p** do meu texto com a intenção que ele desça, porém não sei por qual motivo isso não está funcionando. Toda vez que aplico o `margin-top`, o efeito acaba sendo notado na `div` e não no texto como esperado, como poderão perceber, eu acesso as *boxes* e por fim a *tag* **p** para usar o `margin-top`.

**Segue Código:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

main {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

header {
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 94px;
}

nav {
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 100px;
 top: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;

}

li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

li:hover {
 border-top: 3px solid #b51e1e;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #b51e1e;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 height: 463px;
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: bisque;
}

.container .content {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 45px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

.container .content p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
 <title>Título</title>
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <header class="header">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li>HOME</li>
     <li>SOBRE NÓS</li>
     <li>EQUIPE</li>
     <li>ATUAÇÃO</li>
     <li>CONTATO</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="content">
    <p>O SUCESSO DA SUA EMPRESA<br/> DEPENDE DE BONS JULGAMENTOS</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <footer class=""></footer>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Será que terei que usar `position` para resolver isso?

**P.S.:** Li 2 perguntas semelhantes aqui mesmo no *SO-pt*, no entanto aparentemente não se aplicava ao meu caso específico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque houve uma mesclagem de margens ou seja `content` com `p`, você poderá obter a explicação completa [aqui](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/).

Para resolver basta adicionar `overflow: auto;` ao container ou usar `padding-top`...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

main {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

header {
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 94px;
}

nav {
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 100px;
 top: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;

}

li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

li:hover {
 border-top: 3px solid #b51e1e;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #b51e1e;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 height: 463px;
 background-color: #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: bisque;
}

.container .content {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 45px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

.container .content p {
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
 <title>Título</title>
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <header class="header">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li>HOME</li>
     <li>SOBRE NÓS</li>
     <li>EQUIPE</li>
     <li>ATUAÇÃO</li>
     <li>CONTATO</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="content">
    <p>O SUCESSO DA SUA EMPRESA<br/> DEPENDE DE BONS JULGAMENTOS</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
  <footer class=""></footer>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Em relação a segunda pergunta você pode abrir um outra questão aqui no site caso outros já não tenham aberto, isso ajuda a manter o foco e ajudar mais pessoas.

Comment: Realmente funcionou, irei criar outra pergunta caso não ache nada na web ou até mesmo por aqui. Porém, irei dar uma lida no link sobre a mesclagem de margem que me passou!

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, beleza ? Cara, o que está acontecendo é o seguinte, como a DIV que o `<p>` está tem o `display: block;`, quando você aplica uma margin no seu `<p>` o bloco todo está acompanhando para baixo, até porque o `<p>` está ocupando grande espaço de sua DIV. Se você tirar as cores ou aplicar cores diferentes para cada DIV, vai reparar que o local da div .content não muda, apenas da um espaço de sua nav superior. O que você pode fazer para alterar a posição de seu `<p>` sem interferir nisto, é aplicar um `padding` pois ai ele dará um espaço  interior dentro da tag `<p>` e não exterior como funciona o `margin`. Só mudar o seguinte atributo em seu código CSS:

```
.container .content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

E por fim, mais uma informação.  Caso voce altere o `display` da DIV .content para `display: flex;` vai reparar que a mesma vai funcionar também com o `margin` e não irá " descer " mais.